INSERT INTO with condition check
We have are requirement where we need INSERT INTO DataTable1 for some values if DataTable2 is empty. Unfortunately, DataTable1 and DataTable2 dont have any relation so INSERT INTO ... SELECT .. not work for this case.
Here is sudo code
IF SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DataTable2 = 0
   THEN INSERT INTO DataTable1 VALUES(xx,yy,zz)

However I didnt see any SQL can easy do it.
I try following SQL under Oracle but report error:
INSERT INTO  DataTable1 (object, value_str) VALUES ('object_1', 'NULL') 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DataTable2) = 0
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

We try to avoid use MERGE as we above SQL need run by multiple session and we face the MERGE deadlock issue before. so we change MERGE to INSERT approach.

Please specify what RDBMS you are using. The answer depends on that.

Also note that a WHERE clause don't have to depend on the table being queried to be valid, you can also use a subquery to a completely unrelated table too.

WE need create SQL for three different DBMS platform (Oracle, MSSQL, Postgresql). so firstly i want to get some idea how to write a condition check, then refactoring for all three platform.

I believe your INSERT INTO syntax is incorrect. It should be something like,
INSERT INTO  DataTable1 (object, value_str) SELECT ('object_1', 'NULL')  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DataTable2) = 0 (the NOT EXISTS clause would probably be faster)

Seems you're looking for checking out the existence, then just use NOT EXISTS such as
INSERT INTO DataTable1 ( object, value_str ) 
SELECT 'object_1', null
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM DataTable2 );
/ 

for the case the DB is being Oracle

Thank ,this looks great, One more question, this approach only can INSERT one row each time, is there any way we can INSERT with bulk .like if no condition check, we use bulk INSERT like  : INSERT INTO DataTable1 ( object, value_str )  VALUES('xxx1', 'yyy1') ('xxx2', 'yyy2') ...  ('xxx_n', 'yyy_n').But how to write it with above logic with condition check

Hi @zheng you're welcome. Need to well know about your source. Basically, you can handle the issue by using INSERT INTO DataTable1 ( object, value_str )  SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 'xxx1', 'yyy1' FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'xxx2', 'yyy2' FROM dual ... )  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM DataTable2 ) considering what you have currently presented.
